# Best approach to upload multiples files in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm working in Spring Boot project where I have two entities.

**Client entity** :

```
@Entity
public class Client {

// mapping annotation ...
private Long id;

// mapping annotation ...
private String firstName;

// mapping annotation ...
private String lastName;

// mapping annotation ...
private Set<Document> listDocument;


....

}
```

**Document entity :**

```
   @Entity
    public class Document{

    // mapping annotation ...
    private Long id;

    // mapping annotation ...
    private String name;

    // mapping annotation ...
    private int size;

    // mapping annotation ...
    private Client client;


    ....

    }
```

My app has a form where I set all the information of the clients. Also, I have an input file where I have to upload multiple documents.So, when I click on submit button I have to persist the client information into the database along with all information (doc name,size..) about documents (with client Id) should be persisted in database and then files to be uploaded to the server.

***I'm using Spring Boot with Angular, I'm not asking for code but I just want to know what will the best approach to achieve this according to the best practices.***

Answer (score 2):

I also had a similar Use Case. We have done this with File Zipping approach (*`require less storage`*, *`fast for small documents`* ). When the Client uploads the documents we create the new Zip file and named it in a unique way.
(*not changing the names of original documents*). For example, you can give a unique name with `clientID + uploadTime`.

Now to store there can be multiple ways (for rapid document retrieval)

- Create only one directory (not an ideal way)
- Create directories according to `ClientId`
- Create directories according to `UploadTime (DayWise, MonthWise)`

If *all* the documents are uploaded successfully then you can *save* the information of documents in the table. Note that storing the path of a document can create a problem if the path changes in future so store only name of the document. As here you need to store details of each document you can create two tables. *`One table with id(pk), client Id, zip filename another with id(fk), document name, size etc.`*

you can configure max file-size, max request-size as below in `application properties`

```
MULTIPART (MultipartProperties)
    spring.servlet.multipart.enabled=true # Whether to enable support of multipart uploads.
    spring.servlet.multipart.file-size-threshold=0B # Threshold after which files are written to disk.
    spring.servlet.multipart.location= # Intermediate location of uploaded files.
    spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=1MB # Max file size.
    spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=10MB # Max request size.
    spring.servlet.multipart.resolve-lazily=false # Whether to resolve the multipart request lazily at the time of file or parameter access.
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand the essense of the question.

In my opinion, it's necessary to upload files to the storage first. Operation of upload should be transactional (all or nothing). Error during any file upload fail whole upload. If the upload was successful - then save the information about files to the database.

I suggest to store the following additional information about uploaded files:

1. Date and time the file was uploaded
2. Id of the request. To know that multiple files have been uploaded within one request. You can use time in millis `System.currentTimeMillis()` or UUID `UUID.randomUUID().toString()`

Also, if the system contains a lot of files - I recommend storing files in separate directories to speed up the search. You can store to directories by the time of creation (for example every month new directory), or by the user id. It all depends on the search criteria for the files.

I would recommend you to rename files before store with any unique id (UUID for example) to avoid collisions. Of course you should store original and renamed file names in the database. Also this approach will not allow user to pick up the file name if the directory with files will be open. I mean that users can't guess alien files `https://file-storage/user-john-dou/logo.jpg`

If you are working with images you can think about resize before store.

Comment: Thank you for your time your response is clear , you say that you recommend  to rename files before store with any unique id , so if i want to rename the file with the is of user 
so i have to start with database i mean save the user get its id then start upload file with id user as the file name ? is this correct

Comment: You can't use user id as new file name. Because you can have multiple files for the same user. If you need user id - you can get it from session or JWT token as it is immutable.